# Improvement of the NerdDinner application ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I created an application based on ASP.NET MVC 2 using the popular NerdDinner tutorial provides an easy way for people to find and organize dinners online. I wish in some way to develop this service by adding a few features. This is my first real contact with the programming. I would ask for any hints or suggestions. I have no experience so please bear with me :) Thanks in advance.

1.In NerdDinner application we have in the model class DinnerRepository with query method like below:

```
public class DinnerRepository
{
    private NerdDinnerEntities entities = new NerdDinnerEntities();
    //
    // Query Methods
    public IQueryable<Dinner> FindAllDinners()
    {
        return entities.Dinners;
    }
    public IQueryable<Dinner> FindUpcomingDinners()
    {
        return from dinner in entities.Dinners
               where dinner.EventDate > DateTime.Now
               orderby dinner.EventDate
               select dinner;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to return the value of a given row of the table (in the above code we get the whole, sorted table). For example something like this:

```
return from dinner in entities.Dinners
    WHERE dinner.EventDate like '% 2011-11-28 12:00:01%'
    orderby dinner.EventDate
    select dinner;
```

or `dinner.Category = ‘something’`.

I tried to do this, but it did not work. It will be helpful for me to create a dropdownlist(create and edit method) for different categories of dinners.

2.Adding a language panel. At the top we have the possibility to change the language on the whole website.

3.Sending a confirmation email for people who have confirmed participation in the meeting.
Mail (PDF?) would be generated from the value stored in the database about the meeting and the persons taking part in it. (Maybe database trigger?).

---

**UPDATE:**
Thank you for your response. It was helpful.

Regarding question number 3, I have no idea how to do it. I would be very grateful for any tutorials, examples of solutions, etc. I changed the **NerdDinner** project for my own use in webservice that supports bar.

In short, the case looks like this:

I have two tables: one containing information about a particular dish, the second one contains the ID of the dishes and the name of the person ordering (username of the person logged into the service). The tables are linked by foreign key. Ordering is done by **ActionLink** on the page. After clicking, table of orders is then updated.

I'd like to, on this basis, sent an email to the person who ordered the dish, that contains information about it. Why database trigger is a bad solution?

At this moment I have only implemented an email confirmation for the registration, but I do not think it will be useful. Creating something like this is very difficult? I ask because I'm not specifically familiar with ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Since the method returns an IQueryable you can in your code use LINQ to limit the rows returned. Given you have a instance dinnerRepo you could write something like this:

dinnerRepo.FindAllDinners().Where(d => d.Category = ‘something’);

The Query will get executed when you use this result and not when you call FindAllDinners. More information on LINQ can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query).

2  There should be many tutorials who can give you a explanation how to do that.

3  I would not send the confirmation email fired by a database trigger. You could write a background job that checks your data every night and send the mails then or if this is to long between the runs that you send the email as soon as you finished to store the confirmation in the database.